# How do I add Bean content to solr?

Tags: 7, views, search, blocks

I have a bunch of pages that contain only [beans](https://www.drupal.org/project/bean). I need these pages to show up when searching (using search_api_solr) for words used in those beans.
The bean fields don't show up in the solr field settings page. Any ideas?

Update: though you can create an index containing both nodes and blocks this will just give me the blocks as results and not the pages they are on. Could this be 'fixed' in views?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enable the 'Complete entity view' filter and then select the field 'Entity HTML output'. This will put the entire page in one field including any beans on that page.

I assume there is a better solution but I have not found one yet.

Comment: I think this could be a clean solution. 

When selecting 'Complete entity view' you can specify the view-mode. You could create a view-mode solely for search and use a specific tpl for that view-mode with no HTML but pure data. 

That way the 'Entity HTML output'-field in solr will be clean without HTML garbage.